# Wordpress site Health error with a Bitnami Docker Image and Traefik

Tags: wordpress, docker, traefik, bitnami

I'm using the Bitnami docker container image for WordPress docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6.

I also Traefik use as a reverse proxy.

When checking the site health status in Wordpress admin, I get the following errors :

- The REST API encounter an error : REST API Response: (http_request_failed) cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
- Your site could not complete a loopback request.: Error: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds (http_request_failed)

my docker-compose.yml configuration :

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MARIADB_USER=$MARIADB_USER
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=$MARIADB_PASSWORD
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=$MARIADB_DATABASE

    networks:
      - lan

  wordpress:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6
    restart: unless-stopped
    
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.entrypoints=websecure"
      
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=$WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=$WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=$WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=$WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=$WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=$WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX
      - WORDPRESS_PLUGINS=cCCESS_PERSISTENCE=yes
      - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=640M
      - PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS=10000
      - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=130M
      
    networks:
      - lan
      - web

    extra_hosts:
      - mydomain:192.168.10.2

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  lan:
```

I have tried to enable/disable all Wordpress plugins
I have tried to increase PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT, PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS and PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE
I have tried to add extra_hosts has explained in the docker documentation without success.

Thanks,